# Python pandas - highlight top n max,min values

Tags: python, pandas

How can I highlight top 3 max (or min) values in dataframe column? For example I have:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Values A":[1,2,3,4,5], "Values B":[5,4,3,2,1]})
```

and I want to highlight (I want to be able to choose color for background and text) top 3 values in column `Values A`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `df.style.apply` and a custom function (or a lambda) with the logic. Kindly try:

```
def custom_style(v, props=''):
    return props if v < df.sort_values('Values A',ascending=False)['Values A'].values[2] else None
df_styled = df2.style.applymap(custom_style, props='color:red')
```

Edit:
To show top 5 values in the dataframe, you can simply use:

```
def custom_style(v, props=''):
    return props if v > np.reshape(df2.values, (1,df2.shape[0]*df2.shape[1]))[4] else None
df_styled = df2.style.applymap(custom_style, props='color:red')
```

Comment: Thank you :) What if I would like to highlight max value in each row, not column? And the top 5 values across both columns `Values A` and `Values B`, not for each column separately?

Comment: You can change the axis in the applymap function, and the logic that you'd like to use in the function. I'll edit to show the case for the top 5 values across both columns.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
def format_color_groups(x):
    if x.name<3:
        return ['background-color: yellow', ''] 
df = df.sort_values('Values A')
df.style.apply(format_color_groups, axis=1)
```

Change colors as your requirement.

Comment: Because OP wants to change background and font, not slice.

Comment: Okay will update the answer.